# Do we use cron job to get real time data from firebase?

Tags: laravel

I am working in laravel. I have setup firebase in my admin panel. I want to display real time data in my admin panel. For example last login of user. Do I need to use cron for that? Is that any way in firebase to implement this?

Comment: If you want to create real-time application, you need to use websocket instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) .
Socket.IO is a library that enables real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication between the browser and the server